# Invoke "markdownify" in a Jekyll Plugin

Tags: plugins, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to manually call the `markdownify` filter in a Jekyll plugin. Here is what I have:

```
module Jekyll

class ColumnBlock < Liquid::Block
    include Jekyll::Filters

    def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
        super
        @col = markup
    end

    def render(context)
        text = super

        '<div class="col-md-' + @col + '">' + markdownify(text) + '</div>'
    end
end

end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('column', Jekyll::ColumnBlock)
```

I get the following error: `Liquid Exception: undefined method 'registers' for nil:NilClass`

I am very new to Jekyll and Ruby. What do I have to include when I want to use the `markdownify` filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do not call directly the converter??

See the [source code](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/21c153a8dff20037dbd636232842c73f4d308045/lib/jekyll/filters.rb#L21)

```
def render(context)
    text = super

     site = context.registers[:site]
     converter = site.getConverterImpl(Jekyll::Converters::Markdown)
    '<div class="col-md-' + @col + '">' + converter.convert(text) + '</div>'
end
```

Comment: thx a lot! I tried that by copy/pasting the markdownify function from source but I got the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Update - **getConverterImpl** is deprecated in Jekyll 3, you should use **find_converter_instance** instead :

```
def render(context)
  text = super
  site = context.registers[:site]
  converter = site.find_converter_instance(::Jekyll::Converters::Markdown)
  '<div class="col-md-' + @col + '">' + converter.convert(text) + '</div>'
```